# Vaadin how to print dynamic raw html using PrintUI class?

Tags: java, printing, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm following the example code which puts the html string into a `Label`. The html is perfect in the browser, is multiple pages and so on. However when I do a Print Preview (or Print) the printout is limited to only one page and there is vertical scrollbar on the printout.

How do I print multiple pages and remove the scrollbar?

My code in the `PrintUI` class is only:

```
setContent(new Label(template, ContentMode.HTML));
```

Comment: You will have to specify print styles in css

Comment: Actually it's a lot more complicated than that. I found the answer and will be posting it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found at: https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/3869543/3869542

You basically need to resort to pure html. The following code does this and fixes the issue:

```
private void setSizeUndefined2Print()
{
    com.vaadin.ui.JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("document.body.style.overflow = \"auto\";" +
                                                  "document.body.style.height  = \"auto\"");
    UI.getCurrent().setSizeUndefined();
    this.setSizeUndefined();
}
```

You can find more details in the above link.